# How to subtract only date part of two Java.util.date object?

Tags: java, date

```
   Date dateOne= new Date(121,2,19,23,26,30);
   Date dateTwo= new Date(121,2,20,01,26,30);
   long diff = dateTwo.getTime()-dateOne.getTime();
   TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)  // We need 1, result is 0
```

I understand, why we are getting 0 (The difference in the number of milliseconds does not makeup 24 hours), but I am not able to understand what needs to be done to get 1.
Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `java.util.Date`? Please use `java.time.LocalDate` if you can.

Comment: Sorry. Can't do that. Parameters passed from an external module.
Our function needs to check if the two passed dates belong to the same calendar date, irrespective of time. If not, how much one is lagging the other?

Comment: if dateOne == dateTwo -> You still want 1 day as the difference? Explain the reason when and why do you need 1.

Comment: If dateOne is 19th March 2350 hours and dateTwo is 20th March 0150 hours: We are talking about two different days. .One 19th and the other 20th

Comment: `java.util.Date` represents an instant in time. It doesn't have an associated calendar system or time zone. If two `java.util.Date` instances are (for example) 12 hours apart, whether they occur on the same calendar date depends on the time zone.

Comment: "If dateOne is 19th March 2350 hours" - that can't be represented directly in a `java.util.Date`, because it assumes a particular time zone.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Date to LocalDateTime.

```
Date feedDate= new Date(121,2,19,23,26,30);
Date tarcDate= new Date(121,2,20,01,26,30);
ZonedDateTime feed = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(feedDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime tarc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(tarcDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Now get the duration between the two

```
Duration d = Duration.between(feed, tarc);
System.out.println(d);            // in ISO 8601 format
System.out.println(d.toHours());  // as a long
```

prints

```
PT2H
2
```

And use the following to get the difference in days per [Ole V.V's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) suggestion.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(feed.toLocalDate(), tarc.toLocalDate());
System.out.println(days);
```

prints

```
1
```

Some of Date's methods and constructors are deprecated so it would be best to use classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Though not officially deprecated, I regard `Date` as virtually deprecated.